# setting the normal of a stl loaded model in three.js

Tags: three.js

I loaded a stl model in three.js.
The model is a pipe. The problem is I actually see the inside of the pipe because I think the normal is set towards the center of the pipe, I want to set the normal outwards(I think this would make the outside part of the pipe seen). 
Could any one plz help me solve the problem. When I load other models it seems to be fine but the loaded pipe internals is seen when the pipe is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If other stl-loaded models work, then the data from the pipe stl model is maybe wrong? 
You can easily fix this by iterating over all face normals of the model's geometry and do a .negate() to all the face normal vectors for this model. I think this should do the trick.

If you have created the pipe from a 3D-package yourself, invert the normals there and export it as stl again.